# Login button needs 2x click streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

The problem I’m facing is pertaining to the login button.
The issue is that when user logs in with right credential, then logs out, then logs in again.
In this second login, the user has to click the login button twice.

I don’t know what the issue might be. Has to be with session states but I thought they are persistent even in multi-page app.

Also, as a sidenote, sometimes in the first try when logging in, I get this faulty behavior and need to click again. What might be the issue?

Below is a small sample of the full code.

(My full code can be found at this Github Repository: GitHub - yashmehtakristal/KristalGPT-test: testing the authentication of KristalGPT.

Please refer here for my code: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/login-button-random-behavior/54909

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible code?